# Получить значение формы из iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html-form

Есть страница HTML, на которой подгружается `iframe` форма с другого URL.
Возможно ли получить данные этой формы в главном окне?

Comment: теоретически возможно, но придется потрудиться, если речь идет о еще не отправленных данных на сервер из этой формы. решения через JS точно есть, гуглите, но кажется не во всех браузерах возможно.

Comment: У вас fraime с внешнего URL или с внутреннего?

Answer (score 2):

Можно только если iframe загружает страницу с того же домена.
Вы не сможете получить CrossDomain доступ. Причина тому [Same Origin Policy.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, может здесь, в ссылках, найдете что полезное. Вопросы похожи. А вот если перехватить данные с формы при отправки - это тяжелее.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103407/get-html-inside-iframe-using-jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279682/get-form-values-from-jquery-dialog-iframe

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.